# Laravel 5.3 Join on Field Value

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This Laravel Model Query

```
PostModel::select('posts.*', 'users.name', 'users.user_fullname', 'users.user_gender', 'users.user_picture', 'users.user_picture_id', 'users.user_cover','users.user_cover_id', 'users.user_verified', 'users.user_pinned_post', 'pages.*', 'groups.group_name', 'groups.group_picture_id', 'groups.group_cover_id', 'groups.group_title', 'groups.group_admin', 'groups.group_pinned_post')
                ->leftjoin('users',function($flj){
                    $flj->on('posts.user_id', '=' ,'users.id')
                    ->where('posts.user_type','=','user');
                })
               ->leftjoin('pages',function ($slj){
                   $slj->on('posts.user_id', '=', 'pages.page_id')
                       ->where('posts.user_type','=','page');
               })
                ->leftjoin('groups',function ($tlj){
                    $tlj->on('posts.in_group','=',1)
                        ->whereColumn('posts.group_id', '=', 'groups.group_id');
                })
            ->whereRaw('NOT (users.name <=> NULL AND pages.page_name <=> NULL)')
            ->where('posts.post_id','=',$id)->get();
```

When Query Run Then Give me this Error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause' (SQL: select `posts`.*, `users`.`name`, `users`.`user_fullname`, `users`.`user_gender`, `users`.`user_picture`, `users`.`user_picture_id`, `users`.`user_cover`, `users`.`user_cover_id`, `users`.`user_verified`, `users`.`user_pinned_post`, `pages`.*, `groups`.`group_name`, `groups`.`group_picture_id`, `groups`.`group_cover_id`, `groups`.`group_title`, `groups`.`group_admin`, `groups`.`group_pinned_post` from `posts` left join `users` on `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `posts`.`user_type` = user left join `pages` on `posts`.`user_id` = `pages`.`page_id` and `posts`.`user_type` = page left join `groups` on `posts`.`in_group` = `1` and `posts`.`group_id` = `groups`.`group_id` where NOT (users.name <=> NULL AND pages.page_name <=> NULL) and `posts`.`post_id` = 360)
```

If i run this query direct on database no error 
Query is

```
select `posts`.*, `users`.`name`, `users`.`user_fullname`, `users`.`user_gender`, `users`.`user_picture`, `users`.`user_picture_id`, `users`.`user_cover`, `users`.`user_cover_id`, `users`.`user_verified`, `users`.`user_pinned_post`, `pages`.*, `groups`.`group_name`, `groups`.`group_picture_id`, `groups`.`group_cover_id`, `groups`.`group_title`, `groups`.`group_admin`, `groups`.`group_pinned_post` from `posts` left join `users` on `posts`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` and `posts`.`user_type` = 'user' left join `pages` on `posts`.`user_id` = `pages`.`page_id` and `posts`.`user_type` = 'page' left join `groups` on `posts`.`in_group` = 1 and `posts`.`group_id` = `groups`.`group_id` where NOT (users.name <=> NULL AND pages.page_name <=> NULL) and `posts`.`post_id` = 360
```

And how to use where not in laravel??

Thanks's

Answer (score 0):

You can replace

```
->whereRaw('NOT (users.name <=> NULL AND pages.page_name <=> NULL)')
```

with

```
->whereNotNull('users.name')
->whereNotNull('pages.page_name')
```

Edit:
Replace this

```
->leftjoin('groups',function ($tlj){
                $tlj->on('posts.in_group','=',1)
                    ->whereColumn('posts.group_id', '=', 'groups.group_id');
```

with

```
->leftjoin('groups',function ($tlj){
                $tlj->on('posts.group_id','=', 'groups.group_id');
```

And put the `in_group` before your `->whereNotNull()`

```
->where('posts.in_group', '=', 1)
```

Comment: error is Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '1' in 'on clause'